# When mouse over link click on my ad with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have a button `Download` in my web page. Under this button I have an `iframe`:

```
<iframe width="468px" height="60px" frameborder="0" src="http://ads.xxxxxx.com/show_ad.php?id=12535"></iframe>
```

When a client clicks the `Download` button, is there a way to have it also effectively click on the ad in the iframe below the button?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you need help with?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but it sounds like you are trying to trigger a click on an advertisement when someone actually clicks a button on your page. That sounds rather deceptive to me. You should make your ad appealing enough that they want to click on it. Doing it this way is just dishonest and should be strongly discouraged by all reputable web developers.

Comment: I have too many ad clients to my ad panel and want to make some impressions every 20 page loads

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, if the ad page is something which is internally hosted by you, this is what you may do :

Page 1:

```
<button id="btn">Download</button>
<br>
<iframe width="468px" height="60px" frameborder="0" id="frm1" src="http://ads.xxxxxx.com/show_ad.php?id=12535"></iframe>

<script>
$("#btn").click(function()
{
   $("#frm1").attr("src",$("#frm1").attr("src") + "&click=true");   
});


</script>
```

Page 2 : ( Your ad url )

```
$().ready(function()
{
   if(getUrlParameter('click') == true)
    $("#idOfAdInPage2").click();
});

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

You may look at this fiddle for better understand : http://jsfiddle.net/p5g399L1/

Comment: Thanks but redirect me to my ad page and show only banner... Can we clone mouse when is on link, simulate clicking on ad

Comment: Something like this: http://theme-nulled.com/item/facebook-viral-contest-application/5229072 , view this page every 5 page loads make clone of mouse when set mouse of ">>>> Download <<<<", but needs me for my ad not for adsense